# SQL: Return ID for the most recent date for unique part

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

How would I modify the following query to return Quote.Quote for only the most recent Quote_Date for each unique Part_Number? Since Quote is unique I am unable to return only the first record. I know this has been asked many times in almost the same fashion, however, I cant quite get it right using row_number, rank, partition, derived table, etc...  I am stuck.  Thanks for any help.

```
    Sample
    Quote     Part_Number     Quote_Date
    1              a              1/1/12
    2              a              1/2/12
    3              a              1/3/12
    4              b              1/2/12
    5              b              1/3/12
    6              c              1/1/12

    Desired Results
    Quote     Part_Number     Quote_Date
    3              a              1/3/12
    5              b              1/3/12
    6              c              1/1/12

    SELECT Quote.Quote, Quote.Part_Number, MAX(RFQ.Quote_Date) AS Most_Recent_Date
    FROM Quote INNER JOIN RFQ ON Quote.RFQ = RFQ.RFQ
    GROUP BY Quote.Part_Number, Quote.Quote
    HAVING (NOT (Quote.Part_Number IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will number the maximum dates as '1', because of `partition...order by quote_date desc` clause.

```
select Quote, Part_number, Quote_date,
       rank() over (partition by part_number 
                    order by quote_date desc) as date_order
from sample
```

The rank() function is usually a better choice than row_number() in this case. If you happen to have two rows with the same maximum date for a part number, rank() will number them both the same. To see how that works, `insert into your_table values (7, 'a', '2012-01-03')`, then run the query with rank(). Change it to row_number(). See the difference?

Select from *that* with a WHERE clause.

```
select Quote, Part_number, Quote_date
from 
    (select Quote, Part_number, Quote_date,
            rank() over (partition by part_number 
                         order by quote_date desc) as date_order
    from sample) t1
where date_order = 1;
```

Another approach is to first derive the set of part numbers and the maximum date associated with them.

```
select Part_Number, max(Quote_Date) as max_quote_date
from sample
group by Part_number;
```

Then join that to the original table to pick up whatever other columns you need.

```
select s.Quote, s.Part_Number, s.Quote_Date
from sample s
inner join (select Part_Number, max(Quote_Date) max_quote_date
            from sample
            group by Part_number) t1
        on s.Part_Number = t1.Part_number
       and s.Quote_Date = t1.max_quote_date
order by Part_Number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. I'm not sure if you need the Part_Number where clause, but you included it in your original SQL (as a HAVING clause) so I kept it. I obviously don't know exactly how your data looks, but the important thing is the rest of the sub-select.

```
SELECT a.Quote, a.Part_Number, a.Quote_Date
FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY q.Part_Number ORDER BY r.Quote_Date DESC) AS RowNum,
    q.Quote, q.Part_Number, r.Quote_Date
    FROM Quote q INNER JOIN RFQ r ON q.RFQ = r.RFQ
    WHERE q.Part_Number IS NOT NULL) a
WHERE a.RowNum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

CTEs make it so easy to do and easy to read.

```
;with cte as (
    select
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by Part_Number order by Quote_Date desc) rownum
    from
        @quote
)
select Quote, Part_Number, Quote_Date from cte where rownum = 1
```